# How to parse CSV in node with streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, stream

I have the following Parser:

```
function Parser(options) {
  options = options || {};

  // options.objectMode = true;
  options.encoding = 'utf8';

  Transform.call(this, options);

  this._rawHeader = [];
  this.header = null;
}

util.inherits(Parser, Transform);

Parser.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
  this.push(this._parseRow(data));
  done();
};

// Parse a data row into an object
Parser.prototype._parseRow = function(row) {
  var fields = row.split(";");
  var obj = { code: fields[0], name: fields[1].trim() };
  return obj.toString();
};


var parser = new Parser({});

// Pipe the streams
process.stdin
  .pipe(parser)
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

But, I get:

```
ACARIT21012;CASSA RURA has no method 'split'
    at Parser._parseRow (/Users/pmu/projects/b/s/lib/parser.js:38:20)
    at Parser._transform (/Users/pmu/projects/b/s/lib/parser.js:32:18)
    at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
    at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:582:7)
    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:614:5)
```

I suspect the stream is broken, but not sure how to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data handed to a `Readable` stream is a `Buffer` object, not a `String`. A `Buffer` doesn't have a `split` method. You must manually invoke `toString()` on the data to be able to manipulate it as a `String`.

```
Parser.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
  this.push(this._parseRow(data.toString()));
  done();
};
```